# Firebase target Inactive user audience

Tags: android, firebase

I want to create an Audience in Firebase that consists of users who have not used the app in one day. By doing this, I could target notifications to be sent via the Notifications Console.

I am aware that I can send data to Firebase as a User Property, for example I can define a value like `last_opened_app` to equal current time in ms. But there is no way to compare it to current time to see if its been a day etc. Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Why are you saying that there is no way to compare it to current time to see if its been a day?

Comment: @AlexMamo here's a screen of the Audience setup: http://prntscr.com/j0a7zp as you can see there is just an option to compare values to some number. No functions etc

Comment: @zngb have you found any solution achieve that

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using including and excluding conditions.

Audiences are now dynamic by default, meaning Analytics will automatically include users as soon as they meet your criteria, and automatically exclude users when they no longer do. This allows you to “set and forget” your audiences while they populate, without the hassle of constantly re-evaluating them.

Audiences can be more precisely defined by adding exclusion criteria. For example, you can create a list of users that added an item to a shopping cart and of those users, exclude those who have also made a purchase.

[image: audience steps]
[Dynamic audiences in Google Analytics for Firebase](https://www.blog.google/products/marketingplatform/360/dynamic-audiences-google-analytics-firebase/)